# How to use DateFormatter properly and what causes this error on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui

I'm going to convert the time now from Date() -> String() 
$1 I'd like to specify properties of DateFormatter().
$2 If possible, I would be nice to know the cause of the errors.

First of all, please note that I am a novice programmer and my question is not appropriate because of the first time I ask question on stack overflow and my poor English.
I guess I lack of the knowledge of class and instance method, but I don't know.
I'm waiting for answer in English or Japanese.

This is a piece of code.

```
//Xcode 12.3 Swift 5.3.2 MBAir AppleSilicon - 2020
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()//OK!
//From here
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tokyo")//1
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())//2
    print(dateString)//3
...
```

Error on //1
Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration
Expected '{' in body of function declaration
Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
Expected declaration
Invalid redeclaration of 'dateFormatter()'

Error on //2
Cannot use instance member 'dateFormatter' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Error on //3
Cannot find type 'dateString' in scope
Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
Unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'

[Apple developper documentation DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are caused as you are trying to use dateFormatter before object/self is created. Just put your code inside a func as below and return a string from it and use it on Text. Example:

```
struct ContentView{
     var body: some View {
           Text(calculateDate())
      }
}
private func calculateDate() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()//OK!
        
       //From here
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tokyo")//1
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())//2
        print(dateString)//3
        return dateString
    }
```